# detect barcode scanner from web browser

Tags: browser, detect, barcode-scanner

In a Java EE web application, I need to read data from barcode scanner(connected to the user's machine - client side),display the data in a textbos and send the code back to the server.I think I understood how to do it.

Is it possible to detect whether the scanner is connected/turned on and if not, display a warning in the web page that the scanner is not connected? (using some activex controls or any other method)

Comment: Very often, bar-code scanners come with it's own software so it can be handled as regular keyboard input. Are you sure this isn't the case for you?

Comment: @sshow - The web appln is expected to suport a variety of scanners. I think we can read the input from the scanner and display in the textbox in the usual way. What concerns me is how do I check whether the scanner is active or not and accordingly notify the user in the web page. I agree that this may not be standard one. Kindly advise whether it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 3):

When I did this I simply used a textfield to capture the input from the scanner.
Why do you need to detect the scanner?

Comment: @Victor - Per requirement, we need to check whether the scanner is active or not and accordingly notify the user in the web page. I agree that this may not be standard one. Kindly advise whether it is possible to do that